# Print timestamp of build

Tags: java, gradle

I want my application to print out the timestamp of build, when it is starting.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Built at DATEANDTIMEGOESHERE");
}
```

Output:

`Built at 2021-05-27 12:00`

How can I achieve this? I guess I need to do some preprocessing during my build. I am using gradle.

```kotlin
plugins {
    application
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
}

application {

    mainClass.set("com.mydomain.myapp.Main")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to print the "current timestamp" once the main method is called :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())); // 2021-05-27 16:44:26.666  
}
```

Comment: No, this prints the current time, not the build time.  The OP wants a static string that doesn't change, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @markspace is correct. This is not what I want. I want to print the time of which the project was compiled.

Comment: the original post says "when it is starting", would you please update the description.

Answer (score 0):

Adding below hooks to `build.gradle` can get you timestamps at Start as well as End.

```
gradle.beforeProject {
    Date now = new Date()
    println "\n *** Build Started @ $now  ***"
}

gradle.buildFinished {
    Date now = new Date()
    println "\n *** Build Completed @ $now  ***"
}
```

More Details can be explored from [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle.html).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by replace a string, this is a pretty standard hook supplied by Gradle Documentation and must not need any additional transformation. Could you please share your output ? For me it looks in this manner, `D:\GitHub\Application\Android-test>gradlew.bat assemble

> Configure project :app

 ***** Build Started @ Thu May 27 20:32:42 IST 2021  ***

 ***** Build Completed @ Thu May 27 20:32:42 IST 2021  ***

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
48 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 47 up-to-date`

Comment: He's already shared his output.  The `public static void main` method is his output.  He wants that println statement replaced with one that has the build time.